# What is the Maximum String Length Apps Script can paste to Google Sheets Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to log large `JSON` strings in Google Sheets.

Each script execution produces a JSON with a large number of chars.

I'm curious if there is a limit and I have to be aware of the size of my string.

I use `sheet.appendRow(row);` method.

Comment: 50K.............

Comment: @Cooper, much more, as shown in tests below.

Answer (score 1):

### Documentation

I did not found the documentation about this limit. Please share if you'll find.

### Tests

⚠️Warning! Please be careful with this script and do not run it in your working Spreadsheets as it may crash.

This sample code would test it:

```
function testPaste() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var k = 1000;
  var myString = '-'.repeat(50*k);
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var row = [];
  var iterations = 15;
  for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    row = [myString, myString.length];
    s.appendRow(row);
    console.log('Success - ' + myString.length + ' chars!')
    myString = myString + myString;
  }
}
```

Good news is the script has a huge limit, I've got this max:

```
Success - 409600000 chars!
```

This is 409 Millions of chars. After that the script above throws an error:

> RangeError: Invalid string length

The page did not load with this amount of data in my case, and the last stable version showed ~50M

[image: 50 millions of chars in 1 cell]

### Reproduce tests

1. Create a new Google Spreadsheet
2. Go to Apps Script Editor
3. Paste and run the code above

Test by @[Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike)

> when var `myString = '-'.repeat(536870888)` is put into a cell using
> appendRow, no error occurs. It seems the value can be put. But, when
> var `myString = '-'.repeat(536870889)` is run, an error like RangeError:
> Invalid string length occurs. From this error, it is found that
> `'-'.repeat(536870888)`

### Conclusion

> It seems that when the large value is put into a cell using
> `setValue`, an error related to the limitation of 50000 characters
> occurs. On the other hand, when the large value is put into a cell
> using `appendRow`, it seems that the limitation of 50000 characters can
> be over.

Comment: I think that your question and answer are interesting. Unfortunately, I cannot find the official document related to this situation. But, it seems that when the large value is put into a cell using `setValue`, an error related to the limitation of 50000 characters occurs. On the other hand, when the large value is put into a cell using `appendRow`, it seems that the limitation of 50000 characters can be over. Unfortunately, I cannot still find the official document related to this situation.

Comment: And, I thought that the maximum size of a variable in Google Apps Script might be related to this situation. So, when `var myString = '-'.repeat(536870888)` is put into a cell using `appendRow`, no error occurs. It seems the value can be put. But, when `var myString = '-'.repeat(536870889)` is run, an error like `RangeError: Invalid string length` occurs. From this error, it is found that `'-'.repeat(536870888)` is the maximum value. If this might be the additional information, I'm glad.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, thanks for your test. I've added this information to my answer. This is interesting. In practice every big number is great because it lets to log more information without the error, and even 1M enough for the most of my use cases.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes. I think that the value of `536870888` is large. When this is used, it is required to use `appendRow`. I thought that this might be an important point.